# teradata error while creating sp with cursor

Tags: select, cursor, procedure, teradata

I am new to Teradata and created some stored procedure using cursor and getting this error. Please help

An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT access to(some column in table)
Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between ';' and the 'DECLARE' keyword.'.
 Referring to undefined cursor 'abc'.
An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT access to (some column in table)
An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT access to (some column in table)
 Referring to undefined cursor 'abc'.
 Referring to undefined cursor 'abc'.

Comment: Can you post the actual SPL for the CREATE/REPLACE PROCEDURE command? You have multiple errors that need to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Rob i am able to resolve these and there is other issue i can run the delete statements but if i try to run same in stored procedure i am getting this error:An owner referenced by user does not have DELETE access to db.tablename

Comment: What version of Teradata? Is the user calling the stored procedure the same or different than the user that created the stored procedure?

Comment: this is happening while try to create and version is teradata 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to submit:

`GRANT DELETE ON {Database}.{Table} TO {User Defining Procedure} WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Stored procedures and privileges are a tricky thing. I would suggest brushing up on them in the Teradata DDL and Stored Procedure Language manuals available **[here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html)** for Teradata 13.10. There are subtle nuances that have to be taken into consideration.